# how to allow /.well-known/security.txt in htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to whitelist this file only in **.well-known**  directory .

My htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>
```

my attempts

```
<Files .well-known/security.txt>
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(public|.well-known/security.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Conclusion !
I just want to whitelist **security.txt** file only in **.well-known**  directory

Comment: Could you please do mention **from** which url **to** url you want to redirect OR rewrite OR anything else? Kindly do update your question with same details, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
> ```

This *condition* is in error since the `REQUEST_URI` server variable always starts with a slash, so the expression `!^public` is always successful.

(From this I assume you must have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory, otherwise you would get a rewrite loop.)

Once you realise this then you can modify the rule in the way you had tried. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|\.well-known/security\.txt$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

**HOWEVER**, your other rule blocks all requests for physical files/directories that start with a dot, so the request will still be blocked (with a 403 Forbidden). This rule is also in the wrong place for other requests (it needs to be *before* the rewrite to the `/public` subdirectory).

You are better off making an exception as a separate rule at the start of the file instead. For example, try the following instead:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

# Prevent further processing for special files
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/security\.txt$ - [L]

# Block access to all dot-files
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (^|/)\. - [F]

# Rewrite request to "/public" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

The `<IfModule>` wrapper on that one rule was superfluous.

Comment: @Joukhar, Good that this solution has worked for you, as a reminder(just in case you forgot), you could up-vote answers also, up-vote is different from accepting an answer, cheers and keep posting Good Q & A on this great site.